# how to query a table date against a series of dates on another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, INVOICES and INV_PRICES. I am trying to find the Invoice table's part price from the Inv_Prices based upon the Invoice_Dt on the Invoice table; if the Invoice_Dt is between (greater than, but less than) or greater than the max EFF_DT on the Inv_Prices, then return that part's price.

I have tired variations on the following code, but no luck.  I either do not get all the parts or multiple records.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT A.INVOICE_NBR, A.INVOICE_DT, A.PART_NO,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(A.INVOICE_DT) >= TRUNC(B.EFF_DT) THEN B.DLR_NET_PRC_AM
     WHEN (TRUNC(A.INVOICE_DT)||ROWNUM >= TRUNC(B.EFF_DT)||ROWNUM)  AND (TRUNC(B.EFF_DT)||ROWNUM <= TRUNC(A.INVOICE_DT)||ROWNUM) THEN B.DLR_NET_PRC_AM
     /*MAX(B.EFF_DT) THEN B.DLR_NET_PRC_AM*/
 ELSE 0
 END AS PRICE   
FROM INVOICES    A,
     INV_PRICES  B
WHERE A.PART_NO = B.PART_NO
ORDER BY A.INVOICE_NBR
```

Can someone assist?  I have a sample of each table if needed.

Comment: Sample data would be great! Especially if you add them in one of two ways: either with CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements (only a few rows from each table, but enough to illustrate complexity: for example, have at least a few different part numbers, dates between price dates, dates beyond the most recent date in the price table); or, perhaps easier, as WITH clauses.

Comment: Why do you need to TRUNC the dates from the two tables? If the invoice date and/or the effective price date have time-of-day components, it doesn't seem to make sense to truncate; what if an invoice was created in the morning, but the new price went into effect at 4 PM? Why would the morning invoice get the effective price that wasn't in effect when the invoice was created?

Comment: I truncated to take out time.

Comment: I understand, but I don't understand WHY you wanted to take out time. Either the dates are really just dates (time of day is irrelevant), in which case the dates should be entered with midnight (00:00:00) as the time-of-day component, so they are truncated already; or time-of-day is in fact relevant (something only you and your business know), but then taking out the time component is just plain wrong, business-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it work to put the condition in the `JOIN` conditions?  You can calculate the period when a price is valid using `LEAD()`:

```
SELECT i.INVOICE_NBR, i.INVOICE_DT, i.PART_NO,
       COALESCE(ip.DLR_NET_PRC_AM, 0) as price
FROM INVOICES i LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ip.*, LEAD(eff_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY PART_NO ORDER BY eff_dt) as next_eff_dt
      FROM INV_PRICES ip
     ) ip
     ON i.PART_NO = ip.PART_NO AND
        i.invoice_dt >= ip.eff_dt AND
        (i.invoice_dt < ip.next_eff_dt or ip.next_eff_dt is null)
ORDER BY i.INVOICE_NBR
```

Comment: WOW! I think that is it. I am going to test it against a much larger data set. I did not consider the join you did.